# Simplifying trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry

I am having a lot of problems simplifying the following trig functions, please help:

Simplify: $\sec x\tan x(1 - \sin^2 x)$.

Thank you

Tony

Comment: did you mean $(1 - \sin x)^2$ or $1 - (\sin x)^2$?

Comment: Hint: when all else fails, expand everything out, and express everything in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Comment: (secx)(tanx)(1-(sinx)^2)    (sinx squared)

Comment: I see, sorry I edited your question wrongly - I have made another edit to correct it.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you mean $\sec(x)\tan(x)\left(1-\sin^2(x)\right)$...

Remember that $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$, that $\sec(x) = \frac{1}{\cos(x)}$ and also that $\tan(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$.

Now substituting these identities into your expression we get

$$
\begin{align}
\sec(x)\tan(x)\left(1-\sin^2(x)\right) &= \frac{1}{\cos(x)}\cdot\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\cdot \cos^2(x)\\[6pt]
&= \frac{\cos^2(x)}{\cos^2(x)}\cdot \sin(x)\\[6pt]
&= \sin(x)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Please look at my $\LaTeX$ modifications.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$, $1 - \sin^2 x = \cos^2 x$. So by expressing everything in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$, we have
$$
\frac{1}{\cos x}\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}(\cos x)^2
$$

Answer (score 0):

You may need some practice using the Pythagorean identities, in all of their forms. They are
$$\begin{array}{ll}
(1)&\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x=1\\
(2)&\sec^2 x=\tan^2+1\\
(3)&\csc^2 x=\cot^2+1\\
(4)&\csc^2 x\sec^2 x=\csc^2 x+\sec^2 x\text{   if you really want to get fancy}
\end{array}$$
These should be learned in all of their forms, for example (1) could be rewritten as
$$\sin^2 x=1-\cos^2 x$$
$$\text{or }\cos^2 x=1-\sin^2 x$$
In addition to that a good strategy is to convert everything to sines and cosines (or secants and tangents, or co-secants and cotangents).For example, if we converted your problem into sines and cosines we would have
$$\sec x\tan x(1-\sin^2 x)=\frac{1}{\cos x}\cdot\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\cdot\frac{1-\sin^2 x}{1}$$
which is much easier to deal with